# PHP Simple DOM find isn't working

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

Why doesn't this block of code of the PHP Simple HTML DOM work as expected? It should find all of the `<b>` tags in the HTML document and change their text to "bold text." It doesn't do anything.

```
$contentEdited2 = new simple_html_dom();
$contentEdited2->load($html);

$bolds = $contentEdited2->find('b');

foreach($bolds as $b)
    $b->innertext = "bold text";
```

I have been trying to figure this out for the past hour. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing your original `$html` variable but only a local copy that only exists in the loop.

You can change your loop to:

```
foreach($bolds as &$b)    // assign value by reference
    $b->innertext = "bold text";
```

Or:

```
foreach($contentEdited2->find('b') as &$b)
    $b->innertext = "bold text";
```

Comment: I see. But it still does the same thing (nothing) with that `&`

Comment: @Dan the Man And if you do directly: `foreach($contentEdited2->find('b') as &$b)`? `$bolds` probably needs to be assigned by reference as well...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Can you give me a better example?

Comment: When I do that I get a 500 server error. [Hosted here](http://hakatsir.editoriallc.com/grade/index.php?id=1&1=1.1&2=2.2&3=3.3&4=4.1&5=5.2&6=6.3&7=7.1&8=8.2&9=9.3)

Comment: @Dan the Man That's strange. And if you use: `$bolds =& $contentEdited2->find('b'); foreach($bolds as &$b)`?

Comment: That gets rid of the 500 error. But it still doesn't change the bolds.